# How to use the word 'restricted'?

Tags: meaning-in-context

I have a document that has two different versions: the full version and the limited/restricted version. By limited/restricted, I mean that some sensitive information has been omitted from the full version. Now when I am using the following sentence, it seems confusing:

*You can access the restricted version here. To access the full version, please submit a request.*

This is confusing because usually by 'restricted version', we mean a version that only a limited number of people can access. However, I want to express that this version has limited information and is available to everyone whereas the full version is only available upon request. Is there a better way to express this? Is it not confusing at all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The *canonical* word for removing sensitive information from a document is **redact**.  The version of the document with the information removed is called the **redacted** version.

These words are often used with documents which have been released by a government organization after having removed anything which could pose a security threat if revealed. This is not the only possible context for the word though:  it can be used to describe the removal of sensitive business, medical, court case-related, or any other kind of information from a document.

Source: https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/redact (meanings 2 and 3)

Answer (score 2):

More Alternatives :

The **"Abridged/Censored/Condensed/Summarized Version"** is available to all.
The **"Unabridged/Uncensored/Detailed Version"**, which includes **Sensitive/Confidential Data**, is available on request.

You can tweak these suitably.

Comment: There's a lot of similar options: **edited**, possibly **SFW** or **PG** (which can be used metaphorically).

Answer (score 1):

You could say **publicly available** or **open** or **freely distributed** version and call the one with sensitive information the **restricted access** or **containing confidential information** or just **confidential**.
Several other similar wordings (such as **publicly distributed**) would work depending on the context and exact nature of the information withheld.